# mysql LOAD DATA does not parse correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a csv file with four columns. Structure of this file is as shown below.

```
"Id","Title","Content","Author" "1","......","..............","..." "2",".............","....................","......"
```

The command below

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/data/trn.csv' INTO TABLE TR_DATA FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES ;
```

does not parse correctly and puts wrong inputs to fields. How can I parse correctly?

Comment: Need more information to answer this question. What do you mean my 'puts wrong inputs to fields'. What is the structure of TR_DATA. What is actually inserted into it when you run above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> #### Note
>
> If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` to read the file properly, because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator. Some programs, such as **WordPad**, might use `\r` as a line terminator when writing files. To read such files, use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'`.